# How can I hide indent guide in VsCode Terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to hide these indent lines in Terminal but I don't want to hide them in Editor section.

[image]

Thank you for suggestion.

Comment: ask at the extension repo, maybe for a feature